# Can't find collision with JavaFx shape afrer perspective transform

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, perspective

I have a group of rectangles (or polygons) with dynamicly calculated perspective transform (applied via drag'n'drop). The problem is that coordinates of rectangles are not up to date after this transform and I can't find collision with cars centers. [zones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhWym.jpg)

As you can see on image, wrong zones are green because before drag'n'drop rectangles where on top left of imageVeiw.

Here how I'm trying to find collision:

```
  rectGrpoup.getChildren().forEach(child -> {
        final Predicate<Car> carInZone = car -> {
            final Bounds boundsInLocal = mainController.getImageView().getBoundsInLocal();
            //different image size when detect and display
            Point fixedScalePoint = scaleService.fixScale(new Point(car.getLastCenter()), screenSize, new ScreenSize(boundsInLocal.getHeight(), boundsInLocal.getWidth()));
            //I need help in next line
            return Shape.intersect((Rectangle) child, new Rectangle(fixedScalePoint.getX(), fixedScalePoint.getY(), 10, 10)).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1;
        };

        if (cars.stream().anyMatch(carInZone)) {
          child.setFill(Color.GREEN);
          } else {
          child.setFill(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Where child is rectangle (or I can refactor for polygon) from group. 
Child has cordinates before transform, so predicate doesn't work.

[Presentation of program work](https://youtu.be/AUQpFq58mgA)

p.s. I can provide any code if it help

Comment: If the things you are checking for collision have the same parent, just use `getBoundsInParent()` instead of `getBoundsInLocal()`. The bounds in the parent's coordinate system will account for transforms.

Comment: @James_D, I tried, it doesn't help.
I use imageView bounds just to fix scale of car center point. 
"Bounds" are seems to be not appliable for this at all, as they represent rectangular (x,y,height,width), but my zones have shape of trapeze

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can go the other way? I.e. get the coordinates of your target (`fixedScalePoint`) in the parent coordinate system, and apply the [inverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/transform/Transform.html#inverseTransform-javafx.geometry.Point2D-) of the image's [`localToParentTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParentTransformProperty) to it? Just a guess, it's not really clear exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerspectiveTransform in JavaFX in fact extends class Effect and has nothing similar with real transformations (e.x. Rotate).

And the main difference is described in jdoc of the class:

> Note that this effect does not adjust the coordinates of input events
>     or any methods that measure containment on a {@code Node}.
>     The results of mouse picking and the containment methods are undefined
>     when a {@code Node} has a {@code PerspectiveTransform} effect in place.

This means that changes on your shape are shown visually, but coordinates are not being updated.

Other solutions:

- Work with really 3D, e.x. - reach same effect with PerspectiveCamera
- Get same effect with real transformations like rotation and zoom